# fullCalendar 'refetchEvents' not refreshing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

im working on a rails app where each user has a personal Calendar. I use fullCalendar.js for this. It's loaded on calendar.html.erb and on dayClick() i added a function to open an iframe containing a form. This is the code:

```
<div class="container" id="calendar-cnt">
  <%= render partial: 'calendar' %>
</div>

<script>
$( document).ready( function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( {
        events: '<%=escape_javascript @user_calendar_url %>',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' },
        dayClick: function(startDate) {
            ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            ifrm.setAttribute("src", "<%=escape_javascript @user_calendar_url %>" + "/new?date=" + startDate);
            ifrm.style.width = 600+"px";
            ifrm.style.height = 500+"px";
            $('#iframe').append(ifrm);
            ifrm.addEventListener( "close", function() {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
            }, false );
        }
    } );
});
```

Users create new events filling the form on the iframe. This is working fine.
My controllers create action:

```
def create
  @appointment = @user.appointments.build(appointment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Te problem is on the rendering. The calendar should show the created event immediately, by refreshing the events feed. But this is not working. It only shows the new event by refreshing the page.
I tried adding the code on create.js:

```
$('#iframe', window.parent.document).empty();
$('#calendar', window.parent.document).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
```

And also in events/new.html.erb:

```
<script>
  $(window).unload(function(){
      $('#calendar', window.parent.document).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
  });
</script>
```

I'm not a .js expert, so I'd appreciate any insight on the subject.
Thanks

Comment: Try using a function instead of a url where you return the events, and check if it runs when you refetch.

Comment: It doesnt run at refetch @RichardHermanson. Althought this line is executed: $('#calendar', window.parent.document).fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );

Comment: Could you try checking if $('#calendar') finds the calendar element and then if it responds to other calls such as `clientEvents` and `changeView`?

Comment: It does find $('#calendar'), but calling clientEvents returns, instead of an array containing all events, a single array element with div#calendar.

Comment: Ye, fullcalendar isn't initialized or whatever

Comment: Ouch, but its already working. This is on adding new events..  Anyway, thanks for your help

Comment: Fullcalendar isn't there anyway. If it's that you're not finding the right element or because fullcalendar isn't loaded I don't know. Had the same trouble before, just don't remember what the reason was, sry :/